# How to add if-else condition in BEGIN END statement of the input Query to SQL PLUS

Tags: bash, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, ksh

I have script to load tables from flat text file, so before loading the table I want to truncate the existing tables based on input files availability.
If input file is there truncate the table and load new data from file to table.
So while truncating I want to check if input file is present, so I wrote the code like:

```
truncateTables()
 {
QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES="ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
                    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
BEGIN
      if [$IsFile1 == 'TRUE']
      then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'DELETE /*+ parallel(A,8) */ FROM TableName1 A';
      else
      echo "no input file"
      fi;
      if [$IsFile2 == "TRUE"]
      then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'DELETE /*+ parallel(B,8) */ FROM TableName2 B';
      else
       echo "No input file"
       fi;
       COMMIT;
END;
       /
       ";

       EXECUTE_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES=`sqlplus -s $DB_CONN_STR << EOF
                            SET serverout on feed off heading off tab off   serverout on pagesize 0 trimspool on linesize 1000
                            whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
                            ${QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES};
                            EXIT;
                            EOF`
    retVal=$?
    errorORA=`echo "${EXECUTE_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES}" | grep -i 'ORA' | wc -l`
    errorSP=`echo "${EXECUTE_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES}" | grep -i 'SP' | wc -l`

    if [[ $retVal -ne 0 || ${errorORA} -ge 1 || ${errorSP} -ge 1 ]]
            then
            echo "Exiting with failure.......\n$retVal\n........"
            echo "Delete tables FAIL."
    else
            echo "tables Delete is Successful"
    fi
    }
```

But it seems we can not use if else condition in between BEGIN and end? how we can modify this code so that I can pass it to SQL PLUS? any other way also okay for me.

Comment: What language is that between the BEGIN and END of QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES?  It isn't PL/SQL, which is the language Oracle understands.

Comment: Why is mysql tag selected?

Comment: BEGIN END block contains PL/SQL code, cant we add if else in that?

Comment: Yes you can add an IF else in PL/SQL however your syntax is incorrect.  As Tony Andrews pointed out this looks nothing like PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you mixed PLSQL code and ksh.

It is possible to build your query with conditions from your kornshell. Here is how it would start:

```
truncateTables()
 {
      QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES="ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
                    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
       BEGIN
";

    if [ "$IsFile1" == "TRUE" ]
    then
      QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES=${QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES}"
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'DELETE /*+ parallel(A,8) */ FROM TableName1 A';
;"
    else
      echo "no input file 1"
    fi

    if [ "$IsFile2" == "TRUE" ]
    then
      QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES=${QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES}"
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'DELETE /*+ parallel(B,8) */ FROM TableName2 B';
";
    else
      echo "No input file 2"
    fi

    QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES=${QUERY_TO_TRUNCATE_TABLES}"
              COMMIT;
       END;
/
";
```

Hope this helps